# UL Tag Not Closed

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm struggling to find out where this `<UL>` error is coming from during validation checks. It is saying I have an unopened `<UL>` tag... please can someone assist me as I'm lost as to where this tag is :S.

http://www.mammacoil.com/

Thanks
Kirsty

This is the error:

> Line 67, Column 5: end tag for "ul" which is not finished
>
> `</ul>`
>
> Most likely, you nested tags and closed them in the wrong order. For example `<p><em>...</p>` is not acceptable, as `<em>` must be closed before `<p>`. Acceptable nesting is: `<p><em>...</em></p>`
>
> Another possibility is that you used an element which requires a child element that you did not include. Hence the parent element is "not finished", not complete. For instance, in HTML the `<head>` element must contain a `<title>` child element, lists require appropriate list items (`<ul>` and `<ol>` require `<li>`; `<dl>` requires `<dt>` and `<dd>`), and so on.

Comment: validates fine for me: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mammacoil.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Hmmm must have been having a blonde moment :)

Comment: @Matthew That link shows `Line 67, Column 5: end tag for "ul" which is not finished`

Comment: Hi Curt, Can you see at all where this could be???? Im lost as i have i believed closed off all the ULS :S

Comment: Hi all! This has now been fixed, thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is right there:

`For instance, in HTML the element must contain a child element, ... <ul> and <ol> require <li>...`

You have an empty `<ul></ul>` in your code (in fact, **exactly** where the validator tells you where it is), and that's illegal.